# Найти точку пересечения между маршрутом и границами МКАД

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Ищу координаты пересечения маршрута с МКАД.
По аналогии с примером из песочницы ["Пересечение маршрута с многоугольником на примере МКАД"](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/route_inside_polygon):

- Строю мультимаршрут
- Получаю активный маршрут `let route = this._route.getActiveRoute()`
- Получаю первый путь маршрута `let firstPath = route.model.getPaths()[0]`
- Получаю его сегменты `let segments = firstPath.getSegments();`
- Собираю координаты сегментов в один массив

  ```
  let coords = [];
  for (let segment of segments) {
      coords = coords.concat(segment.geometry.getCoordinates())
  }
  ```
- По аналогии с примером собираю участки путей edges

  ```
  let edges = [];
  for (let i = 1, l = coords.length; i < l; i++) {
      edges.push({
          type: 'LineString',
          coordinates: [coords[i], coords[i - 1]]
      });
  }
  ```
- Создаю geoQuery и получаю элементы пересекающие МКАД

  ```
  let routeObjects = ymaps.geoQuery(edges).addToMap(this._map);
  let boundaryObjects = routeObjects.searchIntersect(this._mkadPolygon);
  ```
- Получаю последний элемент (мне нужны его координаты, чтобы поставить там точку маршрута)

  ```
  let lastBoundary = boundaryObjects.get(boundaryObjects.getLength() - 1);
  ```

Как получить его координаты?

P.S.
Может быть, есть метод проще? Я хочу добавить эту точку в маршрут, чтобы получать параметры маршрута внутри МКАД и после МКАД отдельно.

Получение этой точки с помощью метода [getClosest](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1-dev/ref/reference/IPolygonGeometryAccess-docpage/#getClosest) даёт не корректную точку. Он ищет ближайшую точку по прямой, что не есть ближайшая точка по дорогам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coords = lastBoundary.geometry.getCoordinates()`